# Calling component function from within Cypress test

Tags: angular, e2e-testing, cypress

I have an angular 7 app.  I'm using cypress to test a few canvas/map components.  I need to call a function within a component to verify the geojson being displayed on the map.

While in chrome I call `ng.probe($0).componentInstance.draw.getAll()` via the console and I my data gets logged to the console but when I make the same call in my cypress test:

```
cy.window().then((win) => {
    const res = win.ng.probe($0).componentInstance.draw.getAll();
    console.log(res);
})
```

I get `ReferenceError: $0 is not defined`

How would I go about calling my angular function within cypress?

Answer (score 3):

The variable `$0` only exists inside `chrome-devtools`. It's a reference to the element you've selected in the elements panel, like this (notice the `== $0`):

[image]

You need to get a reference to the actual element via `cy.get`.

```js
cy.get('.some-ng-element').then(($el) => {
  const el = $el[0]  // get the DOM element from the jquery element
  const win = el.ownerDocument.defaultView // get the window from the DOM element
  const component = win.ng.probe(el).componentInstance
})
```